# Next.js App Router with auth0 library causes an error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers')

Tags: next.js, auth0

I'm implementing auth0 using this library

`"@auth0/nextjs-auth0": "^3.0.1"`

I made a route.ts file under this path `/app/api/auth/[auth0]/route.ts`

```
import { handleAuth, handleLogin, handleLogout } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

export const GET = handleAuth({
  async login(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    await handleLogin(req, res, {
      returnTo: `http://localhost:3000/home`,
    });
  },
    async logout(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
      await handleLogout(req, res, {
        returnTo: `http://localhost:3000/home`,
      });
    },
});

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';
```

This didn't work. When I try to login an error occurs. The error is

```
- error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers')
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:265:61)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Any advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to add return

```
import { handleAuth, handleLogin, handleLogout } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

export const GET = handleAuth({
  async login(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    return await handleLogin(req, res, {
      returnTo: `http://localhost:3000/home`,
    });
  },
    async logout(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
      return await handleLogout(req, res, {
        returnTo: `http://localhost:3000/home`,
      });
    },
});

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me resolve the issue. I had to add `/api/auth/callback` to allowed urls list as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a website using Nextjs 13.3, with Javascript...
And for Auth Api I use the Pages as if im able to correctly recollect i had the same issue when I tried with the App router for Auth.
I can say that the auth works perfectly by using App Router for the website and Pages Router for the Authentication. I am using Google Auth for my project, you can edit out and add a few things as per your requirements for TypeScript and your method for Authentication.
`pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js`

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@next-auth/mongodb-adapter"
import clientPromise from "../../../utils/db"

export const authOptions = {
  
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
  session: {
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    jwt: true,  
  },
  providers: [
    // OAuth authentication providers
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET
    })
  ],
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      // Send properties to the client, like an access_token and user id from a provider.
      // This was for my own purpose
      if (user.admin){
        session.user.admin = user.admin
      }
      return session
    }
  }
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

Notify me if you want the code for Mongo adapter and client-promise